# VPNサーバー->プロキシ経由でのインターネットアクセスの可否

Tags: aws, network, vpn

このようなことを実現させたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

iPhoneアプリ->VPNサーバー->プロキシサーバー->通常のインターネット

上記のような経路で通常のインターネットの様々なWebサイトにHTTPアクセスし、
スマートフォンでレスポンスを取得するというものです。

とくに、VPNサーバーを経由させた時に、
ヘッダーを書き換えたり、リクエスト先をプロキシサーバーに変更できるかも知りたいと考えています。

VPNサーバーは自前で構築し、プロキシは既存のものにアクセス予定です。
プロキシは他の人が作成したサーバーのため、何も修正などは行えないですが、
VPNサーバーは何かしらカスタマイズするつもりで、先述のことができるのかどうかが特に気になっています。

ネットワーク周りはほとんとやったことがなく、
どう調べたらよいかもわからない状況です。

とりあえず、AWSのEC2上にOpenVPNを使ってVPNサーバーをたてるのが第一歩かなと考えています。
が、その先にどうしたらよいかは全然見えておらず、どういうステップでこの実現まで至るかも
アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: **"iPhoneアプリ->VPNサーバー->プロキシサーバー->通常のインターネット"** という表記は、ネットワークとノードをまぜこぜにしているので質問の意図や実現したいことが他者に伝わりにくいのではと感じました。例えば(EC2にVPNサーバを立てるなら) **"[iPhoneアプリ]->通常のインターネット->[VPNサーバー]->VPN->[プロキシサーバー]->通常のインターネット"** となるのではないでしょうか。(付け加えると、書かれているようなことを実現するための手段としてVPNサーバが適切かというとそうではないように思えるのですが、なぜVPNサーバが妥当であると考えたのか(あるいは他にもこういったことを行う予定だ)、という点を書かれると回答がつきやすいのではないかと考えます。)

Answer (score 1):

VPNサーバ（OpenVPNなどのアプリケーション）ではヘッダの書き換えなどは出来ません。が、もう1段proxyを追加すればよいです。

```
iPhoneアプリ->(VPNサーバー->プロキシサーバ）->プロキシサーバー->通常のインターネット
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 同じマシンでもいいし別でもいい
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、VPNサーバーではヘッダの書き換えはできないのですね。
おっしゃるように、まずは自前のプロキシサーバーにリクエストを飛ばして、そのプロキシサーバーでヘッダを書き換えるというふうに理解しました。